# How to enable context menu options to open files in XYPlorer, like how windows explorer offers "open with VSCode" on advance-click?

Tags: windows, explorer, file-association, microsoft-file-explorer

Among all the awful things to be said of windows file explorer, there is a gem that I miss about it after switching to XYPlorer. When I right-click in a folder's empty space, I am presented with options such as "open with code" and "open with bash", which are amazing options to have, rather than opening bash, and cd x, cd x, cd x, and so forth to my desired directory. Similarly there are options for certain files to be opened with popular applications.

Does XYPlorer have this functionality, and I'm just missing it? Can it be enabled somehow?
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRaCT.jpg)

I have tried looking in settings, and looked at the xyplorer forum. I thought it would be prudent to ask here as well, as the xyplorer forum is not exactly bustling with activity.

Answer (score 1):

I found my own answer after digging a little further. For anyone looking for the answer to this query:

Open Configuration > General > Custom Event Actions > Right-click on white in file list > select "Pop up folder's context menu".

That's it, it will do what I was wanting it to do.